# thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' has overflowed its stack

Tags: rust, stack-overflow, rust-tokio

The following code aims to map each response (`.for_each`) onto a struct `AggrTrade` and append it to a Polars DataFrame `df` asynchronously.

Something I have noticed is that when the program crashes depends on how it was ran. The length of the DataFrame `df` impacts when the program crashes. If compiled in release mode with `cargo run --release`, the program runs for longer than otherwise (height of 400) as opposed to in debug compiled mode (height of around 60). I am guessing there is an issue with duplicate values and them not being dropped, but I can't find it in the code.

Is this due to how I used `std::sync::{Arc, Mutex}`?

When I disable the lines:

```rust
append_df(&*df, df2).await;

write_parquet(&*df).await;
```

the code runs fine. Here is the rest of the code:

```rust
async fn new_stream(endpoint: &str) -> WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>> {
    let url = "wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/".to_owned() + endpoint;
    let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(&url).await.expect("Failed to connect");
    ws_stream
}

pub async fn new_handler(endpoint: &str) -> tokio::task::JoinHandle<()> {
    let df = Arc::new(Mutex::new(DataFrame::empty().lazy()));
    
    let stream = new_stream(endpoint).await;
    let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        let df = Arc::clone(&df);
        stream
            .for_each(|msg| async {
                match msg {
                    Ok(msg) => {
                        println!("{}", &msg);
                        let jsonmsg: Result<AggTrade, serde_json::Error> =
                            serde_json::from_str(&msg.to_string());
                            
                        let df2 = DataFrame::new(vec![jsonmsg])
                            .expect("Failed to create new dataframe")
                            .lazy();

                        append_df(&*df, df2).await;

                        write_parquet(&*df).await;
                    }
                    Err(e) => {
                        println!("stream error: {}", e);
                    }
                }
            })
            .await
    });
    handle
}

async fn append_df(df: &Mutex<LazyFrame>, df2: LazyFrame) {
    let mut df_edit = df.lock().await;

    *df_edit = concat([df_edit.clone(), df2], false, true).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", df_edit.clone().collect().unwrap());
}

async fn write_parquet(df: &Mutex<LazyFrame>) {
    let mut df_write = df.lock().await;
    if &df_write.clone().collect().unwrap().height() <= &1000 {
        return;
    }
    println!("Writing to disk now!");

    let time = std::time::SystemTime::now()
        .duration_since(std::time::UNIX_EPOCH)
        .unwrap()
        .as_secs();

    let mut file = std::fs::File::create(&(time.to_string().trim() + ".parquet")).unwrap();

    ParquetWriter::new(&mut file)
        .with_compression(ParquetCompression::Snappy)
        .with_statistics(true)
        .finish(&mut df_write.clone().collect().unwrap())
        .unwrap();

    *df_write = DataFrame::empty().lazy();
}
```

Error I receive upon crashing:

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
[1]    29186 abort      cargo run -r
2023-01-13 22:20:14.377 osascript[29344:6199784] NSNotificationCenter connection invalid
```

Comment: Might be unrelated but maybe try replacing `for_each` with a for or while loop. According to the [std docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) it's more idiomatic anyways

Comment: @cafce25 This is a stream, not an iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I have skipped using Polars dataframes and instead did the exact same thing but with my own struct of Vec, Vec and so on, and it is working fine. I have no idea why polars crate is having this weird issue, I suspect it has to do with the `concat` function of polars.